# Getting back MySqlDataAdapter data via azure function HTTP trigger

Tags: c#, html, mysql, sql, azure-functions

This code work locally:

```
string Link = $@"server= <some link that is working> ";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Link);
connection.Open();
string command = $"<some command that is working>";
DataSet database = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
data.Fill(database, "name");
Grid.DataSource = database;
Grid.DataMember = "name";
```

Any idea how can I convert it to Azure function, so that it will return the MySqlDataAdapter and I can read it to the grid?

Hey, can you show how you do the http trigget for this one? I mean if I do:

```
var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://<function trigger address>")
```

how do I connect it to the grid?

Comment: You should return list of objects, instead of datatable if you want to expose this as an API backed by azure function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to return the SQL Data Adapter is:

[image]

And the proper way for  `GridView`  data binding should be like this:

```java
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet output = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(Output, "out");
GridViewOutput.DataSource = Output; // bind directly to DataSet
GridViewOutput.DataBind(); // bind to grid
```

Comment: Hey, can you show how you do the http trigget for this one? I mean if I do:    
var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://<function trigger address>") how do I connect it to the grid?